# Javascript comparing at least one identical pairs in an object

Tags: javascript, python, algorithm, dictionary, comparison

I have two dictionaries (object in JS?), and I want to compare them.

In a while loop, I want to print `True` if at least **one** of the pairs is identical (*i.e.* the dictionary below), as opposed to the whole dictionary being identical (but if the whole dict is identical the statement must still be `True` obviously):

```
my_dict = {"Text1":"Text1", "Text2":"Text3", "text5":"text5"}
```

I know in python it would be like that:

```
while any(key == value for key, value in my_dict.items()):
    ...
else:
    ...
```

But I can’t get my hands on the correct syntax for JavaScript.

Comment: `Object.entries(o).some(([key, value]) => key === value)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) and [`some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) this is a one-liner:

```js
let my_dict = {"Text1":"Text1", "Text2":"Text3", "text5":"text5"}

let answer = Object.entries(my_dict).some(([key,value]) => key == value);

console.log(answer)
```

Comment: Object.entries is the slowest possible solution. It should be avoided. Object.keys is almost twice as fast.

Answer (score 1):

```js
for(var key in obj){
    if(key === obj[key]){
        //Do Something
    } else {
        //Do Something Else
    }
}
```

That iterates through the object, and if the key is equal to the value, then it does something, otherwise it does something else.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`some()` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) on JavaScript arrays which is identical to `any` from Python I think.

```js
let my_dict = {"Text1":"Text1", "Text2":"Text3", "text5":"text5"}

let same_exists = Object.keys(my_dict).some((key) => key === my_dict[key])
console.log(same_exists)
```